# Customer Group ID Trouble in Magento

Tags: php, magento-1.4

I'm working with Magento 1.4.0.1, and I've found what appears to be a bug, but in fixing it I think I've created a new monster. I need some wisdom, here.

#### The Bug

During checkout, the quote model data (from `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote`) which is saved along with the cart stores two fields about the customer directly on the `sales_flat_quote` table: `customer_tax_class_id` and `customer_group_id`. If you examine the core quote model class you'd find a method for the former field which ensures that the tax class ID is re-loaded from DB at every request. Well, what I believe the core team failed to do (at least in this version) was also re-load the latter field: the customer group ID. By failing to re-load the group ID with each call for it, we found that the quote yielded incorrect taxes in the cart totals if the customer group changed after they had already initiated a quote in Magento.

#### The Fix

To solve this, I followed suit along with `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getCustomerTaxClassId` and added the following method to the quote model class:

```
# File: app/code/local/Mymodule/Sales/Model/Quote.php
public function getCustomerGroupId()
{
    $this->setCustomerGroupId($this->getCustomer()->getGroupId());

    return $this->getData('customer_group_id');
}
```

This appeared to solve my problem, so that even if the customer came back to their cart two days later, and their customer group had changed during that time, that a re-collect of totals on the quote would use their current customer group configuration. Well, on to my monster ...

#### The Monster

I discovered today that bundle products in the cart were showing row totals which didn't add up to the cart sub- and grand totals. After looking into it, I noticed that some of the products in the bundle had tier pricing, in this case being applied to the "General" customer group at a minimum quantity of 1.

So in tracing this thing out, I discovered that my new method above, which calls for the current customer on the quote (in this case ***none***), was returning "General" as the customer group every time. Why? Because when I inspect the group ID getter in the customer model, I find this:

```
# File: app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
public function getGroupId()
{
    if (!$this->getData('group_id')) {
        $storeId = $this->getStoreId() ? $this->getStoreId() : Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $this->setData('group_id', Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_ID, $storeId));
    }
    return $this->getData('group_id');
}
```

And since this is an empty customer model (no ID set), it uses the default customer group from system configuration, which is in fact "General."

So what should I do? In one hand, I've solved a problem with stale customer group IDs on the quote table, and in doing so I'm forcing the quote to get a fresh ID from a customer model that's believing it's a new account.

I'm thinking I can solve this by checking if the customer is logged in when fetching the group ID, and if not, fall back to the default `NOT_LOGGED_IN` group ID (0 - which is what I actually want in this case, to avoid applying tier pricing). But somehow I feel like I'm tumbling down a rabbit hole while  there might be a better way altogether to solve this.

Help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - So I tested out my own suggestion, and it seems to work. I extended the customer model, like so:

```
# File: app/code/local/Mymodule/Customer/Model/Customer.php
public function getGroupId()
{
    if (!$this->getData('group_id')) {
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $this->setData('group_id', Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
        } else {
            $storeId = $this->getStoreId() ? $this->getStoreId() : Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
            $this->setData('group_id', Mage::getStoreConfig(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::XML_PATH_DEFAULT_ID, $storeId));
        }
    }
    return $this->getData('group_id');
}
```

Where I'm forcing the "not logged in" group when a customer session cannot be found. It solves my problem; but to be clear, I asked this because I'm afraid of making yet another change that has unforeseen effects.

So I'm still open to better solutions!